# In Shadowrift, can a player user more than one villager per round?

Tags: shadowrift

I've seen multiple mentions on forums and in YouTube videos that a player can only 'use' a single villager per round. However, I don't see anything about this in the rulebook.
All it says about using villagers is:

> **Seek Aid:** You may move a
>   Villager with the Aid term on its
>   description from Town Square
>   to the Town Discard to gain its
>   effect.
>   *Example*: An attacking hero may
>   pay 1 Coin and discard the Smith
>   to add +1 damage to their attack.

The epic actions, which are only allowed once per round, are explicitly called out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no restriction on how many times each hero can Seek Aid in the second edition of Shadowrift.

In [this forum post on BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1673804/rules-seeking-aid-changed-v1-v2-rules), Jeremy Anderson (the game's creator) confirms that the following statement is correct.

> ...under the new rules ALL the villagers in the [Town Square] can now
>   be asked for help and all of them could be asked by a single hero.

He goes on to explain:

> So many of the effects are global or
>   monster-targeting (such as the Baker and Priest, respectively) that it
>   was actually pretty rare the rule would even matter other than
>   requiring the players to do a little fiddly bookkeeping. I agree that
>   I'm all for table-talk and interesting decisions, but this wasn't a
>   consistent enough place to produce them and mostly just penalized
>   smaller player counts (and sure, smaller player counts have an easier
>   game so one could argue that's just a positive balancing element...).
>   It also made little (if any) thematic sense. Limited capacity to
>   perform actions makes sense. Limited capacity to receive help from
>   others...a little less so.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, because it says nothing in the rulebooks, this is a house rule. It is entirely up to you and the other players whether to play with this house rule. Advancing as many villagers as you want, is obviously good for you, but as I said, this up to you and the other players.

Another option is to contact the creators of Shadowrift. They may know the real answer to this question, instead of just my house rule opinion.

Answer (score 0):

[From the ruleset on BGG, page 5](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/80142/shadowrift-rules), the definition of Seek Aid is this:

> Seek Aid in Town: Each hero may seek aid from one Villager
>   per round. This means gaining the effect stated on a Villager
>   in Town. Each Villager may only aid one hero per round.
>   Put any Villagers that aid into the Town discard.
>   (Discarding Villagers to aid does not cause the heroes to lose.)

There's the once per turn restriction.

Comment: Clear. Thanks. The wording for the second edition (which I have) is different and seems to remove this restriction. This explains why I see some people refer to this rule.